# Where to add the classpath in the latest version of Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, build.gradle, ktor

I'm trying to add:

```
classpath classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.5.21"
```

In the latest version of Android Studio's build.gradle file. However, the structure of the build.gradle file seems to have changed in the **latest version(Flamingo)**, and I'm unsure where to add this **classpath.**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried adding the classpath in the buildscript block's dependencies section, but it doesn't seem to work. Could someone please guide me on where exactly I should add the classpath in this structure?

Comment: Try to copy and paste the line from the README https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/tree/84d4af04a688286ad1b51a72130ccda691caff75#gradle

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the latest version of Android Studio, I will also recommend using the latest versions for your libraries. So your build.gradle (Project) file should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gradle_version = '8.0.2'
        kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version "${gradle_version}" apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version "${gradle_version}" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "${kotlin_version}" apply false
}
```

Be also sure to have Java 17 installed.

Comment: Hey Srijan. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes Alex Mamo, your answer solved the problem.